# React Native TypeError store.getState is not a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, redux-saga

Hi guys I'm trying to make my code more readable and pragmmatic.

Using redux-saga in React Native I'm getting some issues.

When I try to load the app I get the error:

> TypeError: store.getState is not a function
>
> This error is located at:
>
> ```
> in Connect(Reprov) (at App.js:17)
> in RCTView (at View.js:44)
> in Provider (at App.js:14)
> in App (at renderApplication.js:34)
> in RCTView (at View.js:44)
> in RCTView (at View.js:44)
> in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:33)
> ```

**src/store/configureStore.js**

---

```
import {createStore, applyMiddleware} from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';
import rootSaga from '../sagas';

export default function () {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
  );

  sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga)

  return store;
}
```

### **src/App.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import AppNavigation from './Navigation';
import store from './store/configureStore';
import Reproof from './screens/Reprov';
import Approval from './screens/Aprov';
import PushNotificationController from './components/Push';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <AppNavigation />
          <Reproof />
          <Approval />
          <PushNotificationController />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are importing the store  as a variable and in the file,it is a function :

`import store from './store/configureStore';`

try this :

```
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
```

then create a variable store

```
const store = configureStore();
```